# Tab competion in bash hangs at “select”

Tags: bash

Tab completion in bash became annoyingly slow today; it was fine yesterday and something changed, but I'm not sure what.

To debug, I ran strace on bash, and then I typed `cd /h` and hit `Tab`. A half a second later, it was autocompleted to `cd /home`. `strace` shows that bash called `select`, which waited for 500ms before timing out. This is the cause of the slowness.

```
Process 5639 attached
read(0, "c", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "c", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "d", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "d", 1)                        = 1
read(0, " ", 1)                         = 1
write(2, " ", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "/", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "/", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "h", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "h", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "\t", 1)                        = 1
select(1, [0], NULL, [0], {0, 500000})  = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
brk(0x2a9e000)                          = 0x2a9e000
```

I then ran the same experiment from a different user, and found that the `strace` output is almost identical, but `select` is never called. Autocomplete is fast (as desired) for this second user.

```
Process 5738 attached
read(0, "c", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "c", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "d", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "d", 1)                        = 1
read(0, " ", 1)                         = 1
write(2, " ", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "/", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "/", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "h", 1)                         = 1
write(2, "h", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "\t", 1)                        = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
brk(0x1c9c000)                          = 0x1c9c000
```

You can clearly see that the call to `select` times out after 500ms. My VM is running bash version `4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` and my local machine is running `4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

If I switch to a different user (root or non-root) the tab completion is fast, and `strace` shows that `select` is never called.

How can I debug this further? Should I just upgrade bash?

Comment: Invoke `set -x` (later you can revert it with `set +x`) and repeat your experiment (without `strace`). It should spew what completion functions do. Maybe you will be able to spot a step where it stalls. 500 ms is not much, so recording the screen (with screen capture software or a smartphone) may help.

Comment: I deleted my .inputrc and the problem went away - see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by deleting my .inputrc. This deletion was accidental, however, and I ended up rewriting it from scratch so I cannot say why the .inputrc was causing this issue.